# Cannot fetch Gmail inbox with JavaMail POP

Tags: java, java-8, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to fetch unread messages from Gmail inbox with Javamail, but I can't. I only retrieve archived messages (from 2011!!!) and I don't know why or how to do it.

Here is my code:

```
public List<DefaultMessage> getLatestNthMessages(Integer numberOfMessages) throws Exception {
    URLName url = new URLName("pop3", "pop.gmail.com", 995, "",username, password);
    Store store = new POP3SSLStore(pullSession, url);
    store.connect();
    Folder inbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");

    inbox.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);

    SearchTerm st = new FlagTerm(new Flags(Flags.Flag.SEEN), false);
    List<Message> msgs = Arrays.asList(inbox.search(st)).stream()
                                                        .sorted((m1, m2) -> m2.getMessageNumber() - m1.getMessageNumber())
                                                        .limit(numberOfMessages)
                                                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    List<DefaultMessage> listOfMessages = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Message message : msgs) {
        listOfMessages.add(wrapperToMessage(message));
    }

    return listOfMessages;
}
```

`pullSession` is instantiated as follows:

```
    Properties pullProps = new Properties();

    pullProps.put("mail.pop3.host", pullHost);
    pullProps.put("mail.pop3.username", username);
    pullProps.put("mail.pop3.port", pullPort);
    pullProps.put("mail.pop3.socketFactory.port", pullPort);
    pullProps.put("mail.pop3.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
    pullProps.put("mail.pop3.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    pullProps.put("mail.pop3.auth", "true");

    pullSession = Session.getInstance(pullProps, null);

    pullSession.setDebug(true);
```

Comment: Shouldn't be the `mail.store.protocol` set to `pop3s` instead of `imaps`?

Comment: @JozefChocholacek I've seen right now, haha. I've updated my post (but unfortunately, is no the problem)

Answer (score 1):

Check your [Gmail settings](http://mail.google.com/mail/?shva=1#settings/fwdandpop) for POP3.

Also, there's lots of things you can improve in your code, although they're not the source of your problem.  Start by fixing all the [common JavaMail mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).

You should not be creating a POP3SSLStore directly.  Use the [Gmail example code in the JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#gmail).

Comment: Thanks @bBillShannon ! I will do it. This code is a first version, I am trying to solve the problem for my team and after that, I want to refactor it... Is not the best as you mention :). I will check the demo and I tell you in a few minutes!